# Displaying a bar code with iTextSharp using Chris Love's Barcode Handler (2 part)

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, barcode

I have a situation where I need to create a number of barcodes as images on a page from a set of UPCs from a database.

Additionally, I also want to be able to produce barcodes which can print as labels to a Dymo LabelMaker.

Googling turned up several options, but it seems that for the LabelMaker it'd be wise to produce the barcodes as PDF?

So, I started looking into iTextSharp which seems good (and free!)

Looking fora  simple way to render a Barcode Image to a page, I found this, which looks to do exactly what I want, but I can only get it to work locally. When uploaded to the server it just shows an empty image.

So part 1 of my questions is, why is this?

I have checked and double checked the web.config file contains everything required and am pretty sure that Adobe Reader is installed on the server (as was suggested by another post in the link). There's a post in the link which says

`Hi, Great article, many thanks. I just wanted to put a small update for those running IIS7, if everything works fine when running locally in VS debug mode, but you get a red x when accessing it remotly, you may need to add the handler in the section as well as/or the i.e.`

Which sounds like it's answering the problem... but doesn't!!

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2008/11/09/A-Quick-and-Dirty-Bar-Code-Image-httpHandler.aspx

Part 2 of my question is, am I heading down the right line to print the individual bar codes to a LabelMaker by using iTextSharp?

Just so you know, I am using .NET 2.0 and coding in VB

Comment: You definitely don't need Acrobat or Reader on the server, iTextSharp is completely independent of that. What happens when you access the resource directly instead of embedded in HTML? http://YOU_SITE/barcode.gif?code=1234567890

Comment: `404 Error, page cannot be found` I wondered if I needed a blank .gif image somewhere, or a reference to it beyond the `<add verb="GET" path="barcode.gif" validate="false" type="BarCodeHandler" />` reference in `Web.Config`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [use a **.ashx** HttpHandler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) you don't have to mess with web config. It's exactly the same:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="barcodeToGif" %>
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Public Class barcodeToGif : Implements IHttpHandler
  Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) _
  Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif"
    Dim Request = context.Request
    Dim barcode As String = Request.QueryString("barcode")
    If barcode Is Nothing Then
      barcode = "39"
    End If
    Dim bc39 As New Barcode39()
    bc39.Code = barcode
    Dim bc As System.Drawing.Image = bc39.CreateDrawingImage( _
      System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White _
    )
    bc.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
      Return False
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

And in your `.html/.aspx` file:

```
<img src='barcodeToGif.ashx?barcode=12345689' />
```

The `src` attribute of the `img` tag must have the same name as the HTTP Handler, in this case `barcodeToGif.ashx`.

Comment: That looks interesting. I've never used anything like this, so forgive my ignorance, how would I pass the actual barcode into that script? I have tried running it, but still get the "file not found"

Comment: The barcode can be accessed the same way as the link you provided. First initialize the `HttpRequest`: `Dim Request As HttpRequest = context.Request`, then later on access the `QueryString` property: `Request.QueryString("MY_QUERYSTRING_PARAMETER") `

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably being really dumb, but I can't get it to work! I see what you're saying, but not sure where to put each line. Does `Dim Request As HttpRequest = context.Request` need to go into my page script, or within the Handler Class? I've tried the latter and am getting an `image not found` problem, having changed the line `bc39.Code = "39"` to `bc39.Code = request.querystring("code")` which is how I read the location of the actual code to render.

Comment: *.ashx files should be mapped by default to work out of the box. You can verify by looking on your server here: `\%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\%VersionNumber%\CONFIG\`. This would **NOT** be the case if you altered your `web.config` by adding `<clear /> as the first node in the `<httpHandlers>` section - that effectively removes the defaults.

Comment: Just updated the answer. Try and access the `.ashx` file **directly** first. For example, if you have a problem somewhere else in your code  that throws an `Exception` and access the `.html\.aspx` page instead, you'll see a image not found. If you **can** access the .ashx **directly**, then it's a problem with your `web.config`

Comment: Argh! Now it works, but again locally only, live it returns a Security Exception, I need to increase the Trust Level. I'll email my web hosts again. It's a shared server and possible that is causing the trouble...

Comment: If your web hosting provider won't allow `Full trust`, download the [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and [build it yourself](http://www.junlu.com/list/27/763881.html).

Comment: Thanks. The hosts have given me full permission now, and it works, but your option seems better, I don't know how to compile a DLL though, so I've asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175868/what-do-i-need-to-build-a-dll

Comment: Download visual studio express, (VB version) go to the source code directory and double click the file named `itextsharp.sln`. Edit `AssemblyInfo.cs` and build the solution. (select `Release` and `Any CPU` in the `Configuration Manager`. You said you're using .NET 2.0, so you might want to see if you can find a 2005/2008 version instead of the 2010 version on microsoft's site.